# Kibana timestamp grater that today at 7 am and smaller than today at 6pm

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

The purpose of my filter in Kibana is to get events which happened today (relative data) from 7 am until 6 pm (an event at 4 am would be thus omitted).

The only field I can query for the date is the timestamp. I has to be grater that today at 7 am and smaller than today at 6pm.

Something like :

```
{
  "range": {
    "@timestamp": {
      "gte": "2023-07-14T09:01:24.075+02:00",
      "lt": "now"
    }
  }
}
```

Something which won't work because it depends on the `now` timestamp :

```
{
  "range": {
    "@timestamp": {
      "gte": "now-10h",
      "lt": "now"
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe something like `now-1d/d+18h` ?!

The manual says something like :

```
Assuming now is 2001-01-01 12:00:00, some examples are:

now+1h - now in milliseconds plus one hour. Resolves to: 2001-01-01 13:00:00

now-1h  - now in milliseconds minus one hour. Resolves to: 2001-01-01 11:00:00

now-1h/d - now in milliseconds minus one hour, rounded down to UTC 00:00. Resolves to: 2001-01-01 00:00:00

2001.02.01\|\|+1M/d - 2001-02-01 in milliseconds plus one month. Resolves to: 2001-03-01 00:00:00
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that `now` changes one every request to match the current time, but you can anchor it to the current day using `/d` and then adding hours as you see fit.

If `now` is `2023-07-17T10:12:23.456Z`, then `now/d` is constant during the day `2023-07-17T00:00:00.000Z`. You can then add 7hours, like this: `now/d+7h` which would also be constant `2023-07-17T07:00:00.000Z`. You just need to make sure that it works the way you like depending on your time zone.

Sample query to select documents between 7am and 6pm today:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "gte": "now/d+7h",
        "lte": "now/d+18h"
      }
    }
  }
}
```